# Dataflow job drain does not end for a long time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Draining of Dataflow streaming job does not end while 1 days.

No error log on stack driver also.

job ID is

> 2018-03-09_00_40_49-15224076611250277770
>
> 2018-02-12_22_35_23-4736481063361562693

What's the problem?

And, How can I know when this drainig job complete? (predict time)

Comment: Heyo, GCP Support here. This seems like the sort of thing that's better handled one-on-one, and thus probably won't do well on Stack Overflow. Anyways, we asked somebody from the Dataflow team to take a look. In the meantime, was there something in our docs that pointed you toward Stack Overflow? We could probably find a better way for people to get these things to us...

Comment: I took a look at the two jobs above, and it appears from the logs that the jobs both drained and shut down about 1.5 minutes after the initial request. Draining allows all in-flight data to finish processing before shutting down. So some delay is expected. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stopping-a-pipeline#drain

Comment: 2019-12-03_06_34_40-5076201936790791229 this job took around 25 minutes to drain. Running with 2 workers.@ScottWegner

Comment: @JesseScherer 4 years later and I still haven't found the answer

Answer (score 1):

Streaming pipelines that throw unhandled exceptions while processing data currently can not be drained.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147124216

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how-are-java-exceptions-handled-in-cloud-dataflow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your job with higher machine type? Maybe it is just a too heavy process for it to drain (lots of data is included).